# How do you describe the following set

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory

Given a set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, what is the best way to describe this set?

I tried something $S = \{(x_1,x_2)|-|x_1|\leq 0\}$ But this assumes that $x_2 = |x_1|$

is there a better way to describe this set?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like
$$\{\,(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid y\le -|x|\,\}. $$

Comment: can you explain y?

Comment: @TheSilenceoftheCows The blue lines are the graph of $y=-|x|$ and the hatched area is everythng below that graph, i.e., with lower $y$.